# Trying to pass data between Python(using nltk and flask) and a html template

Tags: python, flask, nltk

I have a Python code which is using NLTK and Flask for creating a chatbot that works on a local server.
After I run or execute the code, the html page opens on the local server and I give a input, but the input doesn't seem to pass to my python code. A prompt appears on my python console where the chatbot takes the input and runs.

I have tinkered a lot with the code, running different forms of it about 30-40times, debugging it and doing a lot of trial and error.
The below code is the only one that seems to run without any error, but the output displayed by the bot on the Html page is "none".

Any help or advice is appreciated. I'm new to Flask and NLTK. Thank you.

This is my Python code

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

pairs = [
    [
        r"my name is (.*)",
        ["Hello %1, How are you today ?", ]
    ],
    [
        r"how are you ?",
        ["I'm doing good\nHow about You ?", ]
    ],
    [
        r"sorry (.*)",
        ["Its alright", "Its OK, never mind", ]
    ],
    [
        r"hi|hey|hello",
        ["Hello", "Hey there", ]
    ],
]

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def samplefunction():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('new.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        greetIn = request.form['human']
        greetOut = c(greetIn)
        return render_template('new.html',bot1=greetOut)

def c(x):
  chat=Chat(pairs,reflections)
  return chat.converse(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app. run(host='127.0.4.21', port=5000, debug=True)
```

The html template used is - new.html, the following :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BOT</title>
    <script>
        var bot = {{ bot }}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Hello, type something to begin!</h1>
      <form method='post'>
        Human: <input type='text' name='human'><br>
        Bot1: {{bot1}}<br>
        <input type="submit" name="action">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried step by step debugging yet?

Comment: I have, I have removed any errors and bugs. But the program isn't running correctly. I have tried different methods to pass and retrieve data between the main python script and the html template on the local server, it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: When doing step by step debugging, you should see exactly at which line of your code things start to go in the wrong direction

Comment: Will look into that and try it again with different methods. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the code in the nltk.chat.util package, and give a return type for the converse() method, it initially only had a print statement and no return.

The original code was

```
def converse(self, quit="quit"):
        user_input = ""
        while user_input != quit:
            user_input = quit
            try:
                user_input = input(">")
            except EOFError:
                print(user_input)
            if user_input:
                while user_input[-1] in "!.":
                    user_input = user_input[:-1]
                print(self.respond(user_input))
```

The changed code :

```
def converse(self, quit="quit"):
        user_input = ""
        while user_input != quit:
            user_input = quit
            try:
                user_input = input(">")
            except EOFError:
                print(user_input)
            if user_input:
                while user_input[-1] in "!.":
                    user_input = user_input[:-1]
                return(self.respond(user_input))
```

I had to remove the print statement and put a return method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using chat.respond(x) instead of chat.converse.

Comment: Tried that too. I had to change the code in the nltkutil package, and give a return type for the converse() method, it initially only had a print statement and no return.